# time difference when save into mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

client will sent a time to me

```
test['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
```

And My server will convert the time with local timezone

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
tz = get_localzone()
datetime =dateutil.parser.parse(data['datetime']).replace(tzinfo=tz)
print "##### strftime #############"
print dateutil.parser.parse(data['datetime']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "##### tzinfo #############"
print dateutil.parser.parse(data['datetime']).replace(tzinfo=tz)
print "###### isoformat  #######"
print datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz).isoformat()
```

The output like this:

client:

```
2015-11-16T15:38:16.286561
```

server:

```
##### strftime #############
2015-11-16 15:38:16
##### tzinfo #############
2015-11-16 15:38:16.286561+08:06
###### isoformat  #######
2015-11-16T15:38:16.729346+08:00
```

But I check the data save in mongo db has time difference :

```
"datetime" : ISODate("2015-11-16T07:32:28.679Z")
```

I found that if I save `datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz).isoformat()`
the time has no time difference

But I save `dateutil.parser.parse(data['datetime']).replace(tzinfo=tz)` will have time difference

Why would this time difference   happend??

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form.  This means that any datetime values other than UTC will be adjusted by the current timezone offset.